# Maple - Substitute into an expression involving derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, maple

I'm working with some matrices including derivatives like d/dt(x(t)). I need to replace this whole expression {d/dt(x(t))} with something like xdot. I have tried to use "subs", but it seems to refuse to do the substitution.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to realize that `d/dt(x(t)` as text input means nothing special in Maple. The output from issuing `diff(x(t),t)` as a command (or from inserting it as marked up 2D Math input from the palette) does get typeset to look like what you've written. But simply typing `d/dt(x(t))` won't produce a derivative expression and so won't match.

Using an explicit command, we can get the substitution.

```
M := Matrix( [ [ diff(x(t),t) ] ] );

                                 [d      ]
                            M := [-- x(t)]
                                 [dt     ]

subs( diff(x(t),t) = xdot, M );     

                                [xdot]
```

Note that you can also get `diff(x(t),t)` from the Expression palette, both when you create the Matrix as well as when you form that call to `subs`.

I should probably also ask whether you are really trying to substitute the name `xdot` into your Matrix (to allow some other symbolic manipulation?) or whether you are trying to get a typesetting with `x` and `.` over head. If you are actually trying to get it just to appear as $\dot x$ then that can be enabled via by changing the typesetting level,

```
interface(typesetting=extended);
```

After that command (which can also be set via via Tools->Options in the menubar) then by default differentiation with respect to `t` is display as an overhead dot. The `Typesetting:-Settings` command will even allow you to change that behaviour, disabling it, or enabling it for some name other than `t`.

This is a Maple programming question, and not really about mathematics. As such it would be more appropriately asked on stackexchange or [mapleprimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com). If none of the above works for your example then I suggest asking on mapleprimes and uploading your worksheet there.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me solve my problem. What I'm dealing with is a set of dynamical equations involving diffs. In order to linearize the equations, I should calculate the Jacobian matrix. Maple does not accept diff for this. So, that's why I have to do the substitution.